# How do I dynamically generate dates between two dates in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been searching for a good generate_series analog in Snowflake but what I've found so far is a bit limiting in scope. Most of the examples I've seen use `rowcount` but I need something more dynamic than that.

I have these columns:
location_id, subscription_id, start_date, end_date

The datediff of the date columns is usually a year but there are many instances where it isn't so I need to account for that.

How do I generate a gapless date range between my start and end dates?

Thank you!

Comment: I do this quite often, and also haven't found an easier way other than doing generator with rowcount. The only annoying part is you have to dynamically generate the rowcount, or what I do sometimes is just generate an absurd amount of dates and then count on the rest of my process to filter out the dates I didnt want

Comment: @Josh Okay that's what I was afraid of. Was hoping for something a bit more stable. Thanks for answering and confirming.

Comment: You can also use ```recursive CTE```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this, but here's the way I do it with [SQL Generator](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=%22datespine_groups%22&tableState=%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22location_id%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22subscription_id%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22start_date%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22end_date%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22baseTableName%22%3A%22My_First_Table%22%2C%22ddl%22%3A%22%22%7D&formState=%7B%22arguments%22%3A%7B%22group_by%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22location_id%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22location_id%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22subscription_id%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22subscription_id%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A1%7D%5D%7D%2C%22date_col%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column%22%2C%22col%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22start_date%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22start_date%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A2%7D%7D%2C%22start_timestamp%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22timestamp%22%2C%22value%22%3A%222018-01-01T00%3A00%22%7D%2C%22end_timestamp%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22timestamp%22%2C%22value%22%3A%222024-01-01T00%3A00%22%7D%2C%22interval_type%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22date_part%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22month%22%7D%2C%22group_bounds%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22value%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22mixed%22%7D%7D%2C%22transformName%22%3A%22datespine_groups%22%7D) function `Datespine_Groups`.

The reason I like to do it this way, is because its flexible enough that I can add weekly, hourly, or monthly intervals between the dates and reuse the code.

The parameter `group bounds` changes the way the join happens in a subtle way that allows you to control how the dates get filtered out:

**global** - every location_id, subscription_id combination will start on the same start_date

**local** - every location_id, subscription_id has their own start/end dates based on the first and last values in the date column

**mixed** - every location_id, subscription_id has their own start/end dates, but they all share the same end date

Rather than try and make it perfect in 1 query, I think it's probably easier to generate it with `mixed` and then filter out where the `group_start_date` occurs after the `end_date` of your original data.

Here's the SQL. At the very beginning you can either (1) find a way to dynamically generate the 3 parameters, or (2) hard code a ridiculous range that'll last your career and let the rest of the query filter them out :)

You can change `month` to another `datepart`, I only assumed you were looking for monthly.

```
WITH GLOBAL_SPINE AS (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      ORDER BY 
        NULL
    ) as INTERVAL_ID, 
    DATEADD(
      'month', 
      (INTERVAL_ID - 1), 
      '2018-01-01T00:00' :: timestamp_ntz
    ) as SPINE_START, 
    DATEADD(
      'month', INTERVAL_ID, '2018-01-01T00:00' :: timestamp_ntz
    ) as SPINE_END 
  FROM 
    TABLE (
      GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 2192)
    )
), 
GROUPS AS (
  SELECT 
    location_id, 
    subscription_id, 
    MIN(start_date) AS LOCAL_START, 
    MAX(start_date) AS LOCAL_END 
  FROM 
    My_First_Table 
  GROUP BY 
    location_id, 
    subscription_id
), 
GROUP_SPINE AS (
  SELECT 
    location_id, 
    subscription_id, 
    SPINE_START AS GROUP_START, 
    SPINE_END AS GROUP_END 
  FROM 
    GROUPS G CROSS 
    JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT 
        SPINE_START, 
        SPINE_END 
      FROM 
        GLOBAL_SPINE S 
      WHERE 
        S.SPINE_START >= G.LOCAL_START
    )
) 
SELECT 
  G.location_id AS GROUP_BY_location_id, 
  G.subscription_id AS GROUP_BY_subscription_id, 
  GROUP_START, 
  GROUP_END, 
  T.* 
FROM 
  GROUP_SPINE G 
  LEFT JOIN My_First_Table T ON start_date >= G.GROUP_START 
  AND start_date < G.GROUP_END 
  AND G.location_id = T.location_id 
  AND G.subscription_id = T.subscription_id
```

Comment: Thank you @josh! Can definitely work with this.