# How to create expansion of dates, partition by ID in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like this:

```
Start_Date | End_Date   | product ID | etc.
2020-01-01 | 2020-03-02 | 1233       
2021-11-05 | 2021-12-30 | 532...
```

How could I create a table where I get each row on the consecutive Date-ProductID level? Also, the date format shall be converted from **yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-01**. Also, all other columns (under "etc." need to be pasted as well and should be constant. Such as:

```
Date_       | product ID | etc.
2020-01-01  | 1233       
2020-02-01  | 1233
2020-03-01  | 1233
2021-11-01  | 532
2021-12-01  | 532..
```

How would I do this in SQL the most efficient way given that I have 1000s of product IDs? Any guidance is very appreciated.

Comment: mysql or snowflake?

Comment: what have you tried so far? where did you get stuck?

Comment: If you have a string format for the date at all, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @nbk its in snowflake

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I can covert those into date in case they are string.

Comment: if you are not new to sql see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72790020/how-do-i-dynamically-generate-dates-between-two-dates-in-snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to fill in dates using the generator function to generate new rows, but the generator function requires a constant. This complicates dynamic ranges. It's also possible to use recursive CTEs, but that too is a bit complex. I think the easiest way is a user defined table function UDTF. Once it's written, it's simply a matter of calling it with a lateral join (basically, select from the table and then add a comma with the call to the UDTF).

Here's a UDTF that will fill in date ranges:

```
create or replace function FILL_DAYS(MIN_DATE date, MAX_DATE date)
returns table(DT date)
language javascript
as
$$
{
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        const ms = 1000 * 3600 * 24; // Milliseconds per day
        minTime = new Date(Math.floor(row.MIN_DATE.getTime() / ms) * ms);
        maxTime = new Date(Math.ceil(row.MAX_DATE.getTime() / ms) * ms);
        curTime = minTime;
        while (curTime <= maxTime) {
            rowWriter.writeRow({DT:curTime});
            curTime = new Date(curTime.getTime() + ms);
        }
    },
}
$$;
```

One you have that, it's simply a matter of calling it through a lateral join:

```
select DT as THE_DATE, PRODUCT_ID from MY_TABLE,
    table(FILL_DAYS(START_DATE, END_DATE));
```

You mention partitioning by ID. With the sample data here it's not needed but for more complex data you can use partitions with UDTFs:

```
select DT as THE_DATE, PRODUCT_ID from T1
    ,table(FILL_DAYS(START_DATE, END_DATE) over (partition by PRODUCT_ID order by null));
```