# How to create date sequence based on start and end date in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake sql and was wondering how I could create a time series (by month or yyyy-mm-01) for each user based on their start and end date. I have this starting table:

```
userid | start_dt   | end_dt
123    | 2020-01-01 |2020-03-01
355    | 2021-04-01 |2021-05-01
```

Now, how can I create something like this?

```
date       | userid 
2020-01-01 | 123
2020-02-01 | 123
2020-03-01 | 123
2021-04-01 | 355
2021-05-01 | 355
```

I was currently using a date table but noticed that that table has holes. Now I am trying to create my own date table. What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: if your database is Snowflake, please don't tag MySQL as they are unrelated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771192/how-to-create-expansion-of-dates-partition-by-id-in-sql/75772197#75772197

Answer (score 1):

```
with data(userid, start_dt, end_dt) as (
    select * from values
    (123, '2020-01-01'::date, '2020-03-01'::date),
    (355, '2021-04-01'::date, '2021-05-01'::date)
), range as (
    select 
        row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn 
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>1000))
)
select 
    dateadd('month', r.rn, d.start_dt) as date
    ,d.userid
from data as d
join range as r
    on r.rn <= datediff(month, d.start_dt, d.end_dt)
order by 1,2;
```

So using a CTE for the `data`, and also to use as the range table, for the span..

gives:

| DATE | USERID |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 123 |
| 2020-02-01 | 123 |
| 2020-03-01 | 123 |
| 2021-04-01 | 355 |
| 2021-05-01 | 355 |

which can be rewritten to the fake data seperate from the working SQL, we can make the range a sub-select in the JOIN section:

```
with data(userid, start_dt, end_dt) as (
    select * from values
    (123, '2020-01-01'::date, '2020-03-01'::date),
    (355, '2021-04-01'::date, '2021-05-01'::date)
)
select 
    dateadd('month', r.rn, d.start_dt) as date
    ,d.userid
from data as d
join (
     select 
        row_number() over (order by null)-1 as rn 
    from table(generator(ROWCOUNT=>1000))
) as r
    on r.rn <= datediff(month, d.start_dt, d.end_dt)
order by 2,1;
```